# Issue while getting the GridContext on save event of a editable subgrid

Tags: dynamics-crm-365-v9

I'm facing a problem to get gridContext on save event of a editable subgrid. I need to get the data from editable subgrid and do some operations on the form but while getting the grid from gridContext it shows the error message called:

> gridContext.getGrid is not a function

JavaScript code:

[image: JavaScript code]

I'm referring the below MSDN links to get gridContext and grid data.

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/clientapi/clientapi-grid-context
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/clientapi/reference/grids/gridrowdata

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: I have couple of questions: The exec context should have return you the grid, is it? if not its Product bug. I remember we faced similar v9 bug & ended up in some workaround. Did you read this -  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/clientapi/reference/events/grid-onsave anything affects you?

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the parenthesis "()" in the getGrid, since it is not a function.
The correct code would be:

```
var myRows = gridContext.getGrid.getRows();
```